# Put Line Break on content of :after

Tags: html, css

I would like to have a line break before and after `or` word in the content text. I tried with `word-spacing`, but that did not give me the exact style I wanted. I also tried to put `\A`, and it just shows `A` on the text. Is there way to achieve my goal?

Expected:

[image: Expected]

Actual:

```css
#t {
   height: 153px;
  width: 401px;
  border: 1px dashed #5fb6c5;
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
}

#t:after {
   content: attr(data-text);
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 19px;
    color: #000;
    opacity: 0.30;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    top: 50%;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="t" data-text="Drag your image here or Click to add" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I also tried to put \A, and it just shows A on the text.

`\A` would work as an escape sequence for a line break in CSS - but here your context is not CSS, you have a custom data attribute here that you are holding this piece of text in, so the primary context is HTML.

```
data-text="Drag your image here&#10;or&#10;Click to add"
```

`&#10;` is the numeric HTML entity for a line break, and I think using that one makes the most sense here.

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked like a charm. I will set your answer as accepted in 6mins.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this like this

create text as different attributes and split them with "\A" at `after` pseudo

```css
#t {
   height: 153px;
  width: 401px;
  border: 1px dashed #5fb6c5;
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
}

#t:after {
   content: attr(data-text1) "\A" attr(data-text2) "\A" attr(data-text3);
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 19px;
    color: #000;
    opacity: 0.30;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    top: 50%;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="t" data-text1="Drag your image here" data-text2= "or" data-text3="Click to add" />
```

Comment: Hehehe :) It's kinda tricky. I appreciate your different approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a 'hack' to do this. By using two pseudo elements and position them with the use of flex.

It's not the best solution and it involves some changes in html but it does the trick in this specific case.

```css
#t {
  height: 153px;
  width: 401px;
  border: 1px dashed #5fb6c5;
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 19px;
  color: #000;
}

#t:after,
#t:before {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}

#t:after {
  content: attr(data-text2);
}

#t:before {
  content: attr(data-text1);
}
```

```html
<div id="t" data-text1="Drag your image here " data-text2="Click to add">
  <span>or</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

We can also use  HTML tag as below:

```html
<pre>
    <div id="t" data-text="Drag your image here
    or
    Click to add" />
    </pre>
```